# how to get the tensor boolean and use it in the function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am writing a function which need to check by the boolean value of tensor.
Here is the code

```
mask2 = tf.greater(z, tfa_bound)
```

where `z` and `tfa_bound` are tensor with `shape=(4,)` and for example after using session , we can get `[True,False,False,False]`
and i want to using those boolean after the `mask2` result

```
for i in range(4):
   if mask[i]== True:
       ''do something''
   else
       print("False")
```

but the mask is a tensor can't index like this(`mask[i]`) (will always `print("False")`)

is there any way to get the print the same as the mask result ?
I know there is a solution that we can first `sess.run` the mask and get the result back,  but is there any other way to build it before using session?

Comment: use mask2.numpy()[i] if it helps

Comment: hello,The mask2 is a tensor has no attribute numpy

Comment: are you using @tf.function in your code anywhere?

Comment: no , should i use it?

Comment: nope, you should not